# Save Attachments from Multiple Outlook Emails and Rename Using Email Subject Line

Tags: outlook, email-attachments

I haven't a clue what I am doing. :)

I found this script online that allows me to save attachments from multiple emails to a folder on my computer so that I can query them as a group later. I need to save the attachments and rename the attachment using the Subject Line of the email. I this possible? Below is the script I am using.

```
Dim GCount As Integer
Dim GFilepath As String
Public Sub SaveAttachments()
'Update 20200821
Dim xMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim xAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim xSelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim i As Long
Dim xAttCount As Long
Dim xFilePath As String, xFolderPath As String, xSaveFiles As String
On Error Resume Next
xFolderPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(16)
Set xSelection = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
xFolderPath = xFolderPath & "\Attachments\"
If VBA.Dir(xFolderPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
    VBA.MkDir xFolderPath
End If
GFilepath = ""
For Each xMailItem In xSelection
    Set xAttachments = xMailItem.Attachments
    xAttCount = xAttachments.Count
    xSaveFiles = ""
    If xAttCount > 0 Then
        For i = xAttCount To 1 Step -1
            GCount = 0
            xFilePath = xFolderPath & xAttachments.Item(i).FileName
            GFilepath = xFilePath
            xFilePath = FileRename(xFilePath)
            If IsEmbeddedAttachment(xAttachments.Item(i)) = False Then
                xAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile xFilePath
                If xMailItem.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
                    xSaveFiles = xSaveFiles & vbCrLf & "<Error! Hyperlink reference not valid.>"
                Else
                    xSaveFiles = xSaveFiles & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & xFilePath & "'>" & xFilePath & "</a>"
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End If
Next
Set xAttachments = Nothing
Set xMailItem = Nothing
Set xSelection = Nothing
End Sub

Function FileRename(FilePath As String) As String
Dim xPath As String
Dim xFso As FileSystemObject
On Error Resume Next
Set xFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
xPath = FilePath
FileRename = xPath
If xFso.FileExists(xPath) Then
    GCount = GCount + 1
    xPath = xFso.GetParentFolderName(GFilepath) & "\" & xFso.GetBaseName(GFilepath) & " " & GCount & "." + xFso.GetExtensionName(GFilepath)
    FileRename = FileRename(xPath)
End If
xFso = Nothing
End Function

Function IsEmbeddedAttachment(Attach As Attachment)
Dim xItem As MailItem
Dim xCid As String
Dim xID As String
Dim xHtml As String
On Error Resume Next
IsEmbeddedAttachment = False
Set xItem = Attach.Parent
If xItem.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then Exit Function
xCid = ""
xCid = Attach.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F")
If xCid <> "" Then
    xHtml = xItem.HTMLBody
    xID = "cid:" & xCid
    If InStr(xHtml, xID) > 0 Then
        IsEmbeddedAttachment = True
    End If
End If
End Function
```

Comment: @Eugene Astafiev

Comment: @0m3r user:4539709